# Why is window.performance.timing.loadEventStart constant?

Tags: javascript, performance, timing

I don't get it.  According to this Akamai resource, the loadEventStart value should be after *every* thing else has happened. https://community.akamai.com/community/web-performance/blog/2016/08/25/using-navigation-timing-apis-to-understand-your-webpage (see visualization just a bit down the page)

But when I prototype this out, putting a *blocking* script in the HEAD tag, I seemingly get a value (in my case, 300ms or so in Chrome), *immediately* and the value never changes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        const timing = window.performance.timing
        console.log('loadEventStart time => ', timing.loadEventStart - timing.navigationStart)
        console.log('domContentLoadedEventStart => ', timing.domContentLoadedEventStart - timing.navigationStart)
      }, 50)
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }, 1000)
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/PclHiA26mTCwUpLqlbGx?p=preview

I would have expected the value to start out as 0, undefinded, null, or something falsey since the event hasn't ever happened yet.  But it's not.  How is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the load event would start in a HEAD part of HTML. Your script should go in the BODY part.